# Material Design Circular Fab

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

I am trying to learn circular fab but I am getting error on setting

```
final ImageView fabIconNew = new ImageView(this);
    fabIconNew.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_new));
    final FloatingActionButton rightLowerButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
            .setContentView(fabIconNew)
            .build();


    SubActionButton.Builder rLSubBuilder = new SubActionButton.Builder(this);
    ImageView rlIcon1 = new ImageView(this);
    ImageView rlIcon2 = new ImageView(this);
    ImageView rlIcon3 = new ImageView(this);
    ImageView rlIcon4 = new ImageView(this);



    rlIcon1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_contact));
    rlIcon2.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_currency_info));
    rlIcon3.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_exhibition));
    rlIcon4.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_faq));
```

I am getting error on Builder(this)
it is showing cannot resolve symbol Builder
I am trying to make the circular button from here https://github.com/oguzbilgener/CircularFloatingActionMenu
I added the compile time dependency
can some one tell me how to solve this error

Comment: Have you synced your project after adding?

Comment: yes I added the gradl file and synced

Comment: Why not to use Google's own design support library? http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Comment: bro i am just trying to learn circular fab nothing else

Comment: Can you paste your `gradle` file and  the import statements from the file where you are using `FloatingActionButton` ?

Comment: Please don't use ALL CAPS titles. There's no need to shout...

Comment: I will this in mind next time Basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FloatingActionButton` you are trying to use is from the `com.android.support:design` which doesn't have the `Builder()` method.

You need to use the `FloatingActionButton` from  `com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu`.

Remove `import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;` and add

```
import com.oguzdev.circularfloatingactionmenu.library.FloatingActionButton;
```

wherever you want to use `com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu`'s `FloatingActionButton`.